# How to export sass files to dist folder preserving folder structure?

Tags: webpack, sass, node-sass, sass-loader, copy-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to take all the sass files in a particular folder, and copy/transform them into css files in a different folder, preserving the folder structure.  Like:

- src

  - folder1

    - test1.scss
  - folder2

    - test2.scss
    - folder3

      - test3.scss

into

- dest

  - folder1

    - test1.css
  - folder2

    - test2.css
    - folder3

      - test3.css

I'm trying to use copy webpack plugin to copy all the src scss files, and the transform option to use node-sass to convert them, which seems to work, except it won't rename the files to .css and i can't figure how to fix this.  Any ideas?

snip from my webpack.config.js:

```
{
      context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
      from: "**/*.scss",
      to: path.join(__dirname, "dest"),
      transform(content, path) {
        const result = sass.renderSync({ file: path });
        return result.css.toString();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transforming files by using `webpack-copy-plugin` is not really a right way to process your assets. It is more like hackish/anti-pattern way. Instead you, should rely on proper loader pipeline. Webpack loaders are especially designed to handle this task. You need 4 things to accomplish you task.

- For processing SASS/SCSS files, you should use `sass-loader`.
- Use `css-loade`r to convert CSS into CommonJS format.
- Augment your config with `mini-css-extract-plugin` to extract CSS from JS code into actual CSS file.
- Use the [object syntax](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#object-syntax) to specify your SASS target files individually. **This is the key to preserving your folder structure in dist folder**. The key of the **entry object** acts like a folder structure within dist/dest. (See below)

Your configuration would look like:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {

    output: {
        // Whatever name pattern you need.
        filename: `[name]/bundle-[contenthash].js`,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dest')
    },

    entry: {
        'folder1': './src/folder1/test1.scss',
        'folder2': './src/folder2/test2.scss',
        'folder2/folder3': './src/folder2/folder3/test3.scss'
    },

    modules: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [

                    // Mark content for extraction into seperate CSS file
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,

                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                    'css-loader',
                    
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        // Run the actual plugin to extract CSS into separate CSS files
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Whatever name pattern you need
            filename: `[name].css`
        })
    ]

};
```

Adjust your `filename` with the patterns you need.

Alternately, if you wish to stick to the same approach, the `to` parameter of copy plugin configuration accepts the webpack style output patterns. Something similar can work for you:

```
// You can use .css instead of [ext]
to: '[path][name].[contenthash].[ext]'
```

Finally, as one last option, if there are too many SASS files, then you can dynamically construct the Webpack `entry` object using [glob package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) and then using that in your module configuration.

Comment: Sure, i get that, but the # of scss files makes this impractical for the time being, and declaring each one individually isn't an option.  It's hackish because it's the easiest approach right now.

Comment: @Phil Added few more approaches that you can try to solve the problem. Try using output patterns for `to` parameter or consider building the entry object dynamically using glob package.